# CSS Positioning - Remove Spacing

Tags: html, css

I have a table and I want to put the input aside. However, when I do this, the inputs on the right side are reasonably large in spacing. How can I remove?

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td><label for="favorecido">Favorecido:</label></td>
    <td><input style="margin-right: 10px;" type="text" name="favorecido" id="favorecido" value="<?= $queryFornecedor->fields['favorecido']; ?>" size="50" maxlength="100" />
      <td><label for="favorecido_cpf">Favorecido CPF:</label></td>
      <td><input width="80%" type="text" name="favorecido_cpf" id="favorecido_cpf" value="<?= $queryFornecedor->fields['favorecido_cpf']; ?>" size="50" maxlength="100" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="cod_forma_pagamento">Forma de Pagamento:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cod_forma_pagamento" id="cod_forma_pagamento" value="<?= $queryFornecedor->fields['cod_forma_pagamento']; ?>" size="50" maxlength="100" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="agencia">Agência:</label></td>
    <td><input style="margin-right: 10px;" type="text" name="agencia" id="agencia" value="<?= $queryFornecedor->fields['agencia']; ?>" size="50" maxlength="100" /></td>
    <td width="25%"><label for="dv_agencia"> DV:</label></td>
    <td><input width="80%" type="text" name="dv_agencia" id="dv_agencia" value="<?= $queryFornecedor->fields['dv_agencia']; ?>" size="50" maxlength="100" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="num_conta">Nº da Conta</label></td>
    <td><input style="margin-right: 10px;" type="text" name="num_conta" id="num_conta" value="<?= $queryFornecedor->fields['num_conta']; ?>" size="50" maxlength="100" /></td>
    <td width="25%"><label for="dv_num_conta">Digito Verificador da Conta:</label></td>
    <td><input width="80%" type="text" name="dv_num_conta" id="dv_num_conta" value="<?= $queryFornecedor->fields['dv_num_conta']; ?>" size="50" maxlength="100" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Try using a width like `<input style="width: 100%; margin-right: 10px;" type="text" ....>`. Another solution is to divide the 100% over the `<td>` like `<td style="width: 30%"> and so on in one row.

Comment: hmm... on all inputs?

Comment: It's better to use a stylesheet then you have to give the width once for all inputs or for all td's.